# How do I configure matchit.vim to use <tab> instead of %?

Tags: vim

I'm a big fan of the [matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) plugin, but I prefer to jump between matching delimiters with the `<tab>` key. However, it seems that matchit is hard-coded to activate when pressing the % key.

My first thought would be that I would simply put this line in my .vimrc, and change '`%`' to '`<tab>`', thus binding the Match_wrapper call to the tab key:

```
nnoremap <silent> %  :<C-U>call <SID>Match_wrapper('',1,'n') <CR>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work; I'm guessing it has got something to do with the `<SID>` (which as far as I understand is an ID unique to the script?) or the fact that Match_wrapper is script-local. (I'm pretty new to Vimscript)

Thus far I've managed to get by mapping `<tab>` to `%` with 'nmap', but it's a pretty fragile hack.

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Why do you not want to use `noremap`? `nnoremap <tab> %` works for me. So does `nmap <tab> %`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a bit unclear - I WANT to use `nnoremap`, but since the idea of `nnoremap` is not to interfere with other scripts it will have no effect on plugins that remap the %-key, which is what matchit does.

Comment: What I'm unclear on is why you think they don't work.  I do have matchit and tested, both worked the way you seem to want - tab switched between pairs specified in matchit that % wouldn't by default.  And I believe the noremap only applies to patterns that appear in the input, in this case tab.

Comment: Ok, that's weird... I couldn't get it to work with `nnoremap` before, I'll have to try again. What version of matchit are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you know that `%` will *always* be remapped, then using

```
map <Tab> %
```

is safe (absence of `n` in front is intentional: `%` is defined in all modes covered by `:map`). But what you can always do is to replace `<SID>` with `<SNR>{N}_` where `{N}` is the number of the matchit script in the outputs of `:scriptnames`. In a newer vim you can also use `maparg('%', 'n', 0, 1)`, it will output a dictionary that among other values contains `lhs` and `sid`. In this case code may look like this:

```
for s:mode in ['n', 'v', 'o']
    let s:map=maparg('%', s:mode, 0, 1)
    execute s:mode.'noremap <Tab> '.substitute(s:map.lhs, '<SID>', '<SNR>'.s:map.sid.'_', 'g')
endfor
```

In this case

```
for s:mode in ['n', 'v', 'o']
    execute s:mode.'noremap <Tab> '.maparg('%', s:mode)
endfor
```

is also acceptable as “old” (without fourth argument) behavior of maparg is to expand `<SID>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
" <C-I> and <TAB> are the same thing.
" So, I changed <C-I> to <C-O><C-I> and <C-O> to <C-O><C-O> to match.
" I didn't want to lose the <C-I> jump functionality.
noremap <C-O><C-O> <C-O>
noremap <C-O><C-I> <C-I>

" This is what the plugin sets on %. I just set it on <TAB>
onoremap <TAB> :<C-U>call <SNR>41_Match_wrapper('',1,'o')<CR>
nnoremap <TAB> :<C-U>call <SNR>41_Match_wrapper('',1,'n')<CR>
vnoremap <TAB> :<C-U>call <SNR>41_Match_wrapper('',1,'v')<CR>m'gv``
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, just in case, you can also use these mapping (tested with Vim 8.0):

```
nnoremap <silent> <Tab> :normal %<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <Tab> :normal %<CR>m`gv``
```